# How to display a dropdown in Yii CButtonColumn

Tags: php, yii

My requirement is to display a dropdown with add,edit,delete options which onchange event will be redirected to the corresponding action.

Currently I have tried the below piece of code  and the dropdown is getting displayed but problem is  that the value of **edit** option is not set with the id of the record.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'blog-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array('header'=>'Username','name'=>'username', 'value'=>'$data->owner->username'),
        array('header'=>'Company','name'=>'company', 'value'=>'$data->owner->company','filter'=>false), 
        array('header'=>'Blog Title','name'=>'title','filter'=>false),  
        array('header'=>'Created on','name'=>'created_time','filter'=>false),   
        array('header'=>'Latest activity','name'=>'updated_time','filter'=>false),
        array('header'=>'URL','name'=>'subdomain','filter'=>false),
        array('header'=>'Status','name'=>'status','filter'=>false), 
        array('header'=>'Action','class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template' => '<select class="actionList" id="actionList" name="actionList">
                    <option>Choose</option>
                    <option value="1">Moderate</option>
                    <option value="$data->id">Edit</option>
                    <option value="3">Deactivate</option>
                    <option value="4">Export</option>
                    <option value="5">Delete</option>
                    </select>'
        ),  

    ),
));
```

Comment: What is being displayed in the page source for the value attribute ?

Comment: the value show s like <option value="$data->id">Edit</option>

Answer (score 1):

The CButtonColumn template property should be in the format "{buttonName1} {buttonName2}" where some predefined buttons like "update", "view" are provided already by the cButtonClass.

You then can override or define each button using the buttons array and each element of that array can contain the following elements:-

```
'buttonID' => array(
  'label'=>'...',     // text label of the button
  'url'=>'...',       // a PHP expression for generating the URL of the button
  'imageUrl'=>'...',  // image URL of the button. If not set or false, a text link is used
  'options'=>array(...), // HTML options for the button tag
  'click'=>'...',     // a JS function o be invoked when the button is clicked
  'visible'=>'...',   // a PHP expression for determining whether the button is visible
```

)

It sounds as though you will need to extend the CButtonColumn class to add extra options to the button property or even create another property.

see : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/106/using-cbuttoncolumn-to-customize-buttons-in-cgridview/

and the class definition: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#buttons-detail

EDIT:

Alternatively, you could do the whole thing in Javascript, define an Id column with a class such as "myDropDown"

and then in Javascript/jQuery process the column along the lines of:-

```
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('myGridView',"
        els=$('.myDropDown);
        els.each(function(el) { 
                    cellId=el.text();

                    var t = $(\"<select id='cellId' class='mySelect'><option value="edit">Edit</option> ... </select>\");
                    el.html(t);
        });

     $('table.items .mySelect').live('click', function() {
        ...process click event
     });
     ", CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your post. I got clue from one of the post mentioned here 'http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/106/using-cbuttoncolumn-to-customize-buttons-in-cgridview/'. Javascript code definitely seems to be a solution to this issue. Once again thanks.

Comment: In addition to this answer, see this question on SO to get a nice idea on how to create a 'button column' by extending the CDataColumn class for an unordered list menu:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/18398911/3090890

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to use CButton column? Wouldnt be easier do this in simple column?
For example:

```
array('header'=>'Action',
'type'=>raw,
'value'=>CHtml::dropDownlist('actionList','',$action,array(
'ajax'=>array(
    'type' => 'POST',
    'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('yourcontroller/action'),                        
    'data'=>array('action'=>'js:this.value'),
        'success'=>'function(data){
           if (data.redirect!=''){
           window.location.href=data.redirect;
}}'
)
```

This is in your view in your cgridview column. 
In your controller action:

```
public function actionAction()
{
switch ($_POST[action]){
case 'Moderate': echo "redirect":"yourcontroller/moderate";break;
/*Your cases here*/
}
}
```

Maybe its not the best but it will work and do what you need. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
I got answer to my question. Instead of CButttonColumn I used a simple column. Below is the corrected code.

 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'blog-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
     'selectionChanged'=>'
        function(id){
                 id=$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id);
                 selected_message_id=id; // this is the value of currently selected row
        }',

    'columns'=>array(

        array('header'=>'Username','name'=>'username', 'value'=>'$data->owner->username'),
        array('header'=>'Company','name'=>'company', 'value'=>'$data->owner->company','filter'=>false), 
        array('header'=>'Blog Title','name'=>'title','filter'=>false),  
        array('header'=>'Created on','name'=>'created_time','filter'=>false),   
        array('header'=>'Latest activity','name'=>'updated_time','filter'=>false),
        array('header'=>'URL','name'=>'subdomain','filter'=>false),
        array('header'=>'Status','name'=>'status','filter'=>false), 
        array( 'header'=>'Action','type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>'\'
           <select class="actionList" id="actionList" name="actionList">
           <option>Choose</option>
           <option value="1">Moderate</option>
           <option value="\'.$data->id.\'">Edit</option>
           <option value="3">Deactivate</option>
           <option value="4">Export</option>
           <option value="5">Delete</option>

           </select>\'', 
        ),

    ),
));
```