# Custom column in CGridView with Button dropdowns's Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: yii, twitter-bootstrap-3, cbuttoncolumn

I just create [Button dropdowns's Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns) for CGridView column. The button contains sub menus and each of them has attributes such as *href, class, data-*, etc.. which can set through **dropdownMenuItems** attribute in CGridView widget.

In view

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  'ajaxUpdate'=>false,
  'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name'=>'ID',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'$data->ID',
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'NAME',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'$data->NAME',
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'BootstrapButtonDropdownColumn',                                       
            'name'=>'',
            'sortable'=>false,
            'dropdownMenuItems'=>array(
                array('label'=>'<i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit', 'link'=>$this->createUrl('site/update')),
                array('itemClass'=>'divider'), 
                array('label'=>'<i class="icon-remove"></i> Remove', 'link'=>'#', 'itemHtmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'remove-item','data-id'=>'$data->ID','data-toggle'=>'modal'))
        ),
   ),                                              
),
```

Class file

```
class BootstrapButtonDropdownColumn extends CDataColumn {

    public $buttonLabel = 'Action';
    public $buttonClass = 'btn btn-small dropdown-toggle';
    public $buttonHtmlOptions=array();
    public $dropdownMenuItems=array();

     protected function renderDataCellContent($row, $data) 
     {
        $html = '<div class="btn-group pull-right">';

        $buttonOption = $this->buttonHtmlOptions;
        $buttonOption['class'] = $this->buttonClass;
        $buttonOption['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
        $html .= CHtml::htmlButton($this->buttonLabel . ' <span class="caret"></span>', $buttonOption);     

        $html .= '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';

        for ($i=0; $i<count($this->dropdownMenuItems); $i++)
        {
            if (isset($this->dropdownMenuItems[$i]['itemClass']))
                $html .= '<li class="' . $this->dropdownMenuItems[$i]['itemClass'] . '">';
            else
                $html .= '<li>';

            $label = '';
            $link = '#';
            $itemHtmlOptions = null;

            if (isset($this->dropdownMenuItems[$i]['label']))
                $label = $this->dropdownMenuItems[$i]['label'];

            if (isset($this->dropdownMenuItems[$i]['link']) && !empty($this->dropdownMenuItems[$i]['link']))
                $link = $this->dropdownMenuItems[$i]['link'];

            if (isset($this->dropdownMenuItems[$i]['itemHtmlOptions']))
                $itemHtmlOptions = $this->dropdownMenuItems[$i]['itemHtmlOptions'];

            $html .= CHtml::link($label, $link, $itemHtmlOptions);
            $html .= '</li>';
        }

        $html .= '</ul></div>';
        echo $html;
    }
}
```

There's a problem, I'd like to set value to data-id attribute on remove menu item but it not work. When see in Browser Element Inspect **the data-id not contain record id** but it show string **$data->id** instead.

```
  <div class="btn-group pull-right open">
      <button class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" name="yt0" type="button">
          Action <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="/site/update"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</a></li>
          <li class="divider"><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a class="remove-item" data-id="$data->ID" data-toggle="modal" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Remove</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

or see in this [image](http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/712/vpkr.jpg)

Please give me some advice, Thank you.

Comment: It's so strange, even it was wrong, it should have to show $data->ART_CAT_ID instead of $data->ID

Comment: Your code was wrong since you can't access the $data while html option would pass directly into custom class like what `value` treat with column expression

Comment: @Telvin Nguyen Sorry, My bad.

Comment: @Telvin Nguyen Thank for advice but, Is there another way to pass id into class?

Comment: I've pushed my answer below, check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thank for advice but, Is there another way to pass id into class

You have ability to access `$row` and `$data`. I think all you need just add more below line into your custom button class

```
if (isset($this->dropdownMenuItems[$i]['itemHtmlOptions'])){
                $itemHtmlOptions = $this->dropdownMenuItems[$i]['itemHtmlOptions'];
                $itemHtmlOptions['data-id'] = $data->ID; // <==added line, maybe you want to use condition or put it somewhere else instead, depend your decision
            }
```

Of cause now you don't need `'data-id'=>$data->ID` from your view anymore, remove it.